# What are dapp and nodekey?

Tags: go-ethereum, keystore

I'm not sure what each geth directories means, in particular dapp and nodes. I consider these as following. Could you tell me it is correct or not?

- chaindata：blockchain data
- dapp：?
- history：history of commands that user typed
- keystore：the storage of private keys for the ethereum client
- nodekey：the private key of node
- nodes:?